# R axis not displayed

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I am afraid I have lost the plot, literally! Why does the axis command not put an x axis in the following plot? It must be something ridiculous, as I can't simplify much more.

```
yar <- c(.2,.1,.05,.03,.02)
plot(yar,xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your x axis is not appearing is that your placed it in a region of the plot where it is so small that it is not visible as output.  You issued the following plot command:

```
plot(yar, xaxt='n')
```

which is really the same as doing

```
plot(c(1:5), yar, xaxt='n')
```

Since you never specified any x values, the default x value are just the counting numbers 1 through 5 corresponding to y values you *did* specify.

The solution to the problem is to place the x-axis where it will be visible.  Hence you can try the following code:

```
xar <- 0.01*c(1:5)
yar <- c(.2,.1,.05,.03,.02)
plot(xar, yar, xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=xar)
```

Comment: Same answers, just a matter of seconds :)

Comment: Well to be honest I actually like that you used a plot.

Comment: R is quite intelligent about axis scaling, just `plot(xar, yar)` would work and automatically space it out neatly.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `plot` function need two elements (coordinates): x and y. You provided the y coordinates and without user defined x coordinates, R assigns standard `1:n` coordinates where `n` is equal to the number of points, in this case 5.

With your data try this:

```
yar <- c(.2,.1,.05,.03,.02)
plot(yar, xaxt='n')
axis(1, at=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

It has this this output:

[image]

As a solution here is one approach: you can place the x coordinates at the default values selected by R and then you can uses labels as you wish. Look at the following code and especially the `labels` argument of the `axis` function.

```
yar <- c(.2,.1,.05,.03,.02)
plot(yar, xaxt='n')
axis(1, at = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), labels = as.character(sort(yar)))
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Your second approach is not a good idea. You have equal spaced labels that are not numerically equally spaced.

Comment: @thelatemail I strongly agree with you. I like the first one but to be honest I do not like them all because a well done plot, from my point of view, should have x and y coordinates without make a program guessing any of them. But the OP didn't provide them so I decided to made that "unorthodox" code.